# PHP looping through XML error: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, xml

```
function loadFilesToArrays(){
    $notpromo1Array = simplexml_load_file('pages/hegnar/source/1/notpromo-1_08_04_2013_1.xml');
        foreach($notpromo1Array as $xml){
            echo $xml -> getName();
            echo "<br>";
            echo $xml -> ORDREHODE -> SluttkundeNr;
            echo "<br>";
        }
}
```

My XML look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<IS_DATA>
<ORDRER class="linked-list">
    <ORDREHODE>
        <ORDREKUNDENR>10541</ORDREKUNDENR>
        <SluttkundeNr>1240</SluttkundeNr>
                    <AND OTHER PROPERTIES></AND OTHER PROPERTIES>..........
    </ORDREHODE>
    <ORDREHODE>
        <ORDREKUNDENR>10541</ORDREKUNDENR>
        <SluttkundeNr>1344</SluttkundeNr>
                    <AND OTHER PROPERTIES></AND OTHER PROPERTIES>..........
    </ORDREHODE>
    <ORDREHODE>
        ETC ETC ETC ..................
    </ORDREHODE>
</ORDRER>
</IS_DATA>
```

And the XML is properly ended, etc, I used notepad++'s xml validator.

I don't understand why when I call loadFilesToArray function, I get this error Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /path/to/file/page1.php on line 104
The IS_DATA is after all enclosed in curly brackets and single quotes as I have seen lots of people referring to when wanting to echo data from XML having special characters in property names in XML.

Comment: `$xml` already represents `<IS_DATA>` or even `<ORDRER>`. Also please see [the basic simplexml examples](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic) which show that nicely and [for error messages we've got a good reference here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456).

Comment: can you tell me what is exactly on line number 104 ??

Comment: @RavindraShekhawat foreach($notpromo1Array as $xml){

Comment: @Shogoot add a print_r($notpromo1Array); instruction right before the foreach, what does it show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give correct path of your xml file right now a.xml and test.php both in same folder

**a.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<IS_DATA>
<ORDRER class="linked-list">
    <ORDREHODE>
        <ORDREKUNDENR>10541</ORDREKUNDENR>
        <SluttkundeNr>1240</SluttkundeNr>
                    <ANDOTHERPROPERTIES></ANDOTHERPROPERTIES>
    </ORDREHODE>
    <ORDREHODE>
        <ORDREKUNDENR>10541</ORDREKUNDENR>
        <SluttkundeNr>1344</SluttkundeNr>
                    <ANDOTHERPROPERTIES></ANDOTHERPROPERTIES>
    </ORDREHODE>
    <ORDREHODE>
        ETC ETC ETC ..................
    </ORDREHODE>
</ORDRER>
</IS_DATA>
```

**test.php**

```
    <?php
$notpromo1Array = simplexml_load_file("a.xml");
foreach($notpromo1Array as $xml)
  {
    foreach($xml as $child)
    {
        echo $child->getName();
        echo "<br>";
        echo $child->SluttkundeNr;
        echo "<br>";
    } 
  }

 /*RESULT
  * ORDREHODE
    1240
    ORDREHODE
    1344
    ORDREHODE
  */

?>
```

Comment: Please check my updated answer .You need multiple loop to access those elements.

Comment: ofc now i see and understand, each for each variable contains a array.
This solves my challenge! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to debug your code:

```
foreach ($notpromo1Array as $xml)
{
    echo $xml->getName(), "\n";
}
```

This gives you the name of the element represented by `$xml`:

```
ORDRER
```

As this element does not have any `<IS_DATA>` child, simplexml gives you `NULL`. And then you access `->ORDRER` on `NULL` which does not work as it is not an object:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

That simple it is. Just access the correct elements and you're fine:

```
foreach ($notpromo1Array as $xml)
{
    echo $xml->getName(), "\n";
    echo $xml->ORDREHODE->SluttkundeNr, "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
ORDRER
1240
```

Comment: I did as you suggested and your right on the output, strange thing though, my function is not looping. Look at my output: http://imageshack.us/content_round.php?page=done&l=img94/3492/notlooping.png

Comment: You're really starting with this I guess. Check the basic simplexML examples I've linked in the comment directly under your question, it has very nice examples and you step away from your own code which often gives a better view on things as well. You need to specify which elements you want to loop over, e.g. `$xml->ORDERHODE as $orderhode`. Simplexml does not know by reading your brain ;)

Answer (score 0):

just made a quick test and here's what I came up with. Replace your **foreach** code for this one:

```
foreach($notpromo1Array as $xml){
   echo $xml->ORDREHODE->SluttkundeNr;
   echo "<br />";
}
```

FYI, I used the following XML file as example and it printed 1240:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<IS_DATA>
    <ORDRER class="linked-list">
        <ORDREHODE>
            <ORDREKUNDENR>10541</ORDREKUNDENR>
            <SluttkundeNr>1240</SluttkundeNr>
        </ORDREHODE>
    </ORDRER>
</IS_DATA>
```